# Using Constructor(props) without Class Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, searchbar

I have created a search bar in TypeScript but for now I am unable to type anything into it. All the control component tutorials that I have seen suggest to use constructor(props) or so. If I use it in my code, I get errors.

Is there any way to use it without having a class component?

For instance, I am using a const() for my page. Is there any way I can make the search bar of this functional?

```
const userSearchPage = () => (
  <div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <div className='main-content'>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <DropDownMenu >
          <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Search By" />
          <MenuItem value={1} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="First Name" />
          <MenuItem value={1} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Last Name" />
        </DropDownMenu>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
   <SearchBar
        onChange={() => console.log('onChange')}
        onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
        style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800
        }}
     />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you also show the code for the SearchBar component?

Comment: @sylar12 it is already there - I apologise for the bad indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the useState hook in a functional component.

```
const userSearchPage = () => {
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
return (
  <div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <div className='main-content'>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <DropDownMenu >
          <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Search By" />
          <MenuItem value={1} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="First Name" />
          <MenuItem value={1} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Last Name" />
        </DropDownMenu>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      <SearchBar
        onChange={(value) => setValue(value) }
        value={value} 
        onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
        style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)} ;
```

Comment: Should I put all of this in a function? If I replace my existing code with your snippet, I get multiple errors. For eg: ```React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "userSearchPage" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks```

Comment: With onRequestSearch, I get an error that: ```Binding element 'onRequestSearch' implicitly has an 'any' type.```and this with target: ```Property 'target' does not exist on type 'string'```

Comment: The onRequestSearch & target errors still persist if I put all of this in a function Search()

Comment: I made some changes, try this one.

Comment: Still not working. I get ```React Hook “useState” is called in function “app” which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function``` type error.

Comment: It works for me. Check this example out: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-darwin-q6dqr

Comment: Ahh I see, in your sandbox, you're exporting a function. Here, it's a const(), which is why I am unable to use a ```const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');```inside it

Answer (score 0):

Props in functional component's are simply parameters!

```
function SearchBar (props) {
  let searchbartext = document.getElementById('searchbartext')
  searchbartext.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    props.onChange(e)
  }
  return ( 
    <form onsubmit={(e) => props.onRequestChange(e)}>
      <input id="searchbartext" style={props.style} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

```
const UserSearchPage = () => {
  function onRequestSearch (e) {
    console.log.('request search', e)
  }
  function onChange(e) {
    console.log('onChange')
  }
  return (
  {SearchBar({
        onChange:onChange,
        onRequestSearch:onRequestSearch,
        style:{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800
        }
     })}
  )
}
```

Edit: you also have to call functional component's as functions, not with `<>` syntax like class components. I used the term "props" inside SearchBar(props) but it's just following Reacts naming convention. You could just as easily replace it with SearchBar(bananas).

Comment: Could you please help me understand how I can use this in my existing code? If I write this function as it as and then call it within my const UserSearchPage(), what parameters will I use?

Comment: I'm typing on a touch screen so I'm not typing it ALL but I think this integrates my code into your solution? Ask me if something needs more explanation.

Comment: Nope, if I copy this function into my code, I get errors on props and on change: ```Type '{ onchange: (e: any) => any; style: any; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've updated my snippet, mind giving it another go?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I get the same error on onChange.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the way parameters are passed in the snippet.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Yup, on OnChange.

Comment: That's weird because my new snippet doesn't use arrow functions. Are you sure you saved and transpiled?

Comment: ```Type '{ onchange: (e: any) => any; style: any; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'onchange' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'```